# How can I require all fields matching a regular expression with laravel?

Tags: php, regex, validation, laravel, laravel-5

I am making an application where users can upload questions, and questions can have multiple correct answers. The correct answers have names of the form correctAnswer1 correctAnswer2 etc.

I want to know how to require all submitted fields matching this pattern; I was thinking of using something analogous to

`/correctAnswer[0-9]/ => 'required'`

Comment: Do you mean checking for multiple options [like this](https://regex101.com/r/yT1hJ7/1)?

Comment: There's a regular expression validation rule: https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/validation#rule-regex

Comment: @JoelHinz that rules is not what I need; that matches a given field against the regular expression. I want to require all fields that match a regular expression.

Comment: @noob I want to require all fields (elements that have been submitted from the form) that are of that form.

Comment: @user3856986: So what should be correct format of input ? Give some examples of correct and wrong input.

Comment: Did you checked the demo I made in the very first comment ?

Comment: @noob I may not have worded the question clearly. I am not looking to validate the form of the input, but rather require all inputs of a given form. Meaning, require all fields of the type matching that regular expression in your demo.

Comment: Am still confused on what you want to say. Take your time to phrase it clearly.

Comment: Yep don't really get what you want to do exactly...

Comment: Isn't what you want redundant? If you want to add this rule when validating, means that they were already submitted and are part of the input. So making them required is useless, since the fact that they are part of the request input means they will pass the rule anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure of the logic behind your requirement, kinda seems you should do things in a different manner, but again I do not know how your app works so I can't be a judge of that. So if the user can add new correct answers fields on the form, and you wan't them to not be empty it makes some sense.

You can't have a regex in the rule name but you can do the following:

```
$rules = [
  // your other rules
];

$correctAnswers = preg_grep( '/^correctAnswer[1-9]{1}$/', array_keys($this->all()));

// use $this->all() when in Http\Requests\YourRequest
// if you are not using the request method of validation (you validate in controller)
// simply replace $this->all() with $request->all() or Input::all().

foreach ($correctAnswers as $correctAnswer) {
  $rules[$correctAnswer] = 'required';
}

return $rules;
```

This assumes you are using the Laravel 5, `Http\Requests` to validate your input. If you are doin'g the validation elsewhere (in controller for example), just replace `$this->all()` with `$request->all()` or `Input::all()`. I can't give the exact choice as I do not know exactly how you do the validation and what version of laravel you use.

PS: This will match only `correctAnswer1` to `correctAnswer9`. If you want more just play with the `[0-9]{1}` part of the regex.